Entry grid widget identifier with tkinter gui
On this link is this code example that generates a entry grid:
from tkinter import *
 
 
class Table:
     
    def __init__(self,root):
         
        # code for creating table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                 
                self.e = Entry(root, width=10, fg='blue',
                               font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
                 
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j])
 
# take the data
lst = [(1,'Raj','Mumbai',19),
       (2,'Aaryan','Pune',18),
       (3,'Vaishnavi','Mumbai',20),
       (4,'Rachna','Mumbai',21),
       (5,'Shubham','Delhi',21)]
  
# find total number of rows and
# columns in list
total_rows = len(lst)
total_columns = len(lst[0])
  
# create root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
t = Table(root)
root.mainloop()

This is the output:

I want to update 1st row, 2nd column. How do I do that? I know that once I named an Entry I can use the following code:
    self.e.delete(0, END)
    self.e.insert(0, "update string")

but since I used grid I do not know how to identify one particular Entry from that grid.
Thanks.

Please focus on one question at a time. You seem to be asking both about placement and how to update a specific cell.

You can create a 2-D list to store the references of those Entry widgets, then you can use this list to update the entry you want.
Also I would suggest:

pass lst to Table.__init__() instead of accessing it directly
create class methods to get and set value of specific entry using row and column

from tkinter import *


class Table:

    def __init__(self, root, values):

        total_rows = len(values)
        total_columns = len(values[0])

        # create a 2-D list to store the entry widgets
        self.entries = [[None]*total_columns for _ in range(total_rows)]

        # code for creating table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                e = Entry(root, width=10, fg='blue', font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
                e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                e.insert(END, values[i][j])
                self.entries[i][j] = e  # store entry into list

    # function to get value of entry at (row, col)
    def get(self, row, col):
        try:
            return self.entries[row][col].get()
        except IndexError as ex:
            print("Error on Table.get():", ex)

    # function to set value of entry at (row, col)
    def set(self, row, col, value):
        try:
            self.entries[row][col].delete(0, "end")
            self.entries[row][col].insert("end", value)
        except IndexError as ex:
            print("Error on Table.set():", ex)


# take the data
lst = [(1,'Raj','Mumbai',19),
       (2,'Aaryan','Pune',18),
       (3,'Vaishnavi','Mumbai',20),
       (4,'Rachna','Mumbai',21),
       (5,'Shubham','Delhi',21)]

# create root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

t = Table(root, lst) # pass lst to Table()

# update entry at row 0 column 1
t.set(0, 1, "hello")

root.mainloop()


Thank you! Exactly what I have asked. If you can help me further? how can I individually use the .bind("", self.method_calling). I want to trigger methods when clicking on a particularly entry.

@i33SoDA It is better to raise another question on that if you have issue on binding.

Yes! I'll do! You cannot imagine how happy you made me. Thanks

You can cycle through the children of the grid (i.e. root) by using the function root.winfo_children(), which would contain a list of the children of the frame. Alternatively, you can manually create a multi-dimensional array, similar to the lst list you have created, and cycle through that!
